# Import subtitles from spreadsheet into Aegisub?

Tags: subtitles, .srt

I have a set of timed transcripts in a spreadsheet in the following form:

```
Timecode mm:ss:ff  |   Line of dialogue
01:02:25           |   This is some dialogue
```

I would like to import them into [Aegisub](http://aegisub.org), running on Mac OSX.
Is there an easy way to do this?
Note that I do not have start & stop times for subtitles, only start times.
Ideally I would make each line of subtitles remain on screen until the next one was due to take over, then manually adjust them in Aegisub afterwards.

I know that Aegisub can [import plain text scripts](http://docs.aegisub.org/manual/Editing_Subtitles), but this doesn't appear to include importing timecodes for some strange reason?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I Couldn't find a way to import into Aegisub, but If the subtitles are in a standard spreadsheet such as Excel, I saved as other format and chose Tab delimited text. Copy all the data in this text file and paste into Subtitle Edit. Then adjust limits on times (Will not overlap the next start time). Then save in whatever format you'd like to use in Aegisub.

I suggest you to use Subtitle Edit because of it's VERY simple sync feature with the video as well as these other abilities. At least it works and you can use Aegisub for your more familiar uses.

Comment: Does subtitle edit exist on Mac OS X? I couldn't find it..